# how to send invoked event to JS function from hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this pattern `href="javascript:stop(this);` pass the hyperlink object to stop function, but i also want to pass invoked event to that function. how can i do that? my records are getting load through ajax so cant attach `.click(function(event){})` with it. and if i attach click on each AJAX call then web slows down on IE6.

please guide me

Thanks

Comment: i want to prevent the default action of link for some reason because on bases of some flag i want to put delay in hyperlink processing

Comment: Oh its 2012 year give up with IE6 and 7!

Comment: If you develop for IE6 to work as fast as modern browsers, I can only hope you're being paid by the hour.

Comment: any idea how can i send event from hyperlink? on document ready i am binding .click with all <a> but records loaded from ajax are not attached to that click event as the are loaded after document.ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have jQuery so you can use delegates/live events instead of inline events or those nasty `javascript:` hrefs:

```
$('#parent').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    // you can use this and e (the event) here
});
```

`#parent` needs to be an element that already exists and will contain the newly added elements. `a` is the selector to match the elements inside `#parent` on which you want the click events to trigger. You may use `$(document)` instead of `$('#parent')` to resemble `.live()` from older jQuery versions, but using a parent element that is closer to the inner elements is better for performance reasons.

Comment: browser gives me this error `Object doesn't support this property or method` on `$('#parent').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    // you can use this and e (the event) here
});
`

Comment: You need to use a recent jQuery version - preferably 1.7.2. If you do not have 1.7, use `$('#parent').delegate('a', 'click', function(e) {});` instead (or upgrade to 1.7.2!)

Comment: Nice... delegate works for me... .live() also worked for dynamically added list..